# Windows Forms designer - How to prevent deletion of child controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-time

There is what appears to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665654/how-to-prevent-the-windows-forms-designer-and-the-user-to-delete-children-of-cus)

I've got a baseform with a property called Buttons. It's simply a generic list of Button objects. This is visible for derived forms in the property grid of the Forms designer and backed by a CollectionEditor. When a button is added via the Collection Editor it is added to a control on the base form, when it's deleted, it's removed from the form.

The problem is that the user can also remove it from the form manually by selecting it and clicking delete.

How can I force the user to use the Collection Editor via the Buttons property and prevent them from making changes directly on the designer surface?

Comment: You can't, unless you create a custom designer for the form so you can explicitly suppress attempts to delete the button.  Not easy to get going.  Re-think the wisdom of having that Buttons property.  You can always find buttons back through the Controls property.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that's exactly what I needed to do. I've created a custom designer and everything now works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire thing up as a User control.

Then like a compound user control, you can't twiddle with it's contents, unless you have access to the control.

So they can delete the entire thing, or they can use it's facility to mess with the buttons.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable suggestion but I've tried that and the behaviour is exactly the same. The button control that is added to the panel on the usercontrol is still selectable in the forms designer and can be deleted independently.